# Can filters be applied automatically to collections when updating from a data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, collections

**The short version of this is: Do I need to refresh a view manually for a filter to be applied to a collection with data binding or can it be done as part of the normal data binding process?**

I have a `DataGrid` that I am trying to keep up to date automatically. One of the things I'd like to do is exclude items that have a certain value set to `true`. Here is the code I'm using to achieve this. It's a bit pieced together from various places but it should get the point across. It may seem like a rather large wall of code but I've tried to keep the snippets as small as possible while keeping my intentions discernible.

This is the code that sets up the filter I am applying to the collection:

```
CollectionView processView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ProcessBox.ItemsSource);
processView.Filter = ProcessFilter;
// Elsewhere
        private bool ProcessFilter(object item)
        {
            ProcessContainer thisItem = item as ProcessContainer;
            if (thisItem.IsScheduled == true)
                return false;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterInput.Text))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return (thisItem.ProcessName.IndexOf(FilterInput.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
            }
        }
```

Down the road I have an input that allows the user to filter the list by text. This *works*, however it uses a manual update.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ProcessBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

Here is the xaml for the datagrid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessBox" SelectionMode="Extended" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,0,33" CanUserReorderColumns="False" MinColumnWidth="50" CanUserResizeRows="False">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsScheduled}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Memory" Binding="{Binding Memory}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have the red text triggers to make sure that it's all being bound and set correctly. My model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the color on the list *will* automatically update the color when that boolean is changed. That is, when I set the boolean's value, this runs:

```
    public bool IsScheduled
    {
        get { return isScheduled; }
        set { isScheduled = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

... and the color changes as expected, but the filter doesn't run.

## So to summarize...

I am filtering an `ObservableCollection<T>` with my own code, and it works when I update it manually. My model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and the data trigger in the xaml picks up the changes, and the collections themselves update as expected when items are added or removed. However if I try to enable the boolean that triggers exclusion in the filter, it will not be hidden until a manual `Refresh()` is called on the view.

Is there a way to make it update automatically or do filters need to be applied by a manual refresh?

Comment: also where is the code that sets up the filter?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder the filter setup is in the very first code section. I'm "using" MVVM with a very basic understanding of what it is, but I'm pretty sure the way I have it set up at the moment qualifies.

Comment: where does the filter code execute - in the code behind of the View or in the ViewModel?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder The filter code is in the code behind

Comment: and the IsScheduled property, does this exist in the ViewModel?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder It is in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MVVM I would suggest moving the code which sets up the filter into the ViewModel and if the IsScheduled property is exposed on the ViewModel as well then it will be easy to trigger a refresh of the filter, may be something like this:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ExampleChildViewModel> _items;
    private readonly ListCollectionView _filteredItems;

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        _items = new RadObservableCollection<ExampleChildViewModel>();
        _filteredItems = new ListCollectionView(_items) {Filter = MyFilter};

        // todo - fill the items...
    }

    public IEnumerable Items { get { return _filteredItems; } }

    public bool IsScheduled
    {
        get { return isScheduled; }
        set
        {
            isScheduled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

            _filteredItems.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private bool MyFilter(object item)
    {
        ExampleChildViewModel thisItem = item as ExampleChildViewModel;
        if (thisItem == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (thisItem.Name == "AwkwardCoder")
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```